Azure pipelines cannot connect to Azure SQL via AD/Entra using a custom console application
I have an Azure Pipeline that needs to invoke a Console application (.exe) which connects to multiple databases to perform EF core migrations. The databases can only be accessed via Azure AD/Entra (i.e. having Authentication=Active Directory Default; in the connection string)
A service principal exists in Azure AD for the DevOps project, and is configured with the "Contributor" role against the subscription. I'm confident the permissions are correct as I have previously used the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 task against a database with no issue.
The task looks like:
  - script: |
      cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/ef-migrator-exe
      echo "Connection string: ${{ parameters.masterConnectionString }}"
      EfMigrator.exe -c "${{ parameters.masterConnectionString }}"    
    displayName: 'Execute EF Migrations'     

However, when running the .exe from the pipeline I'm getting:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

From what I've read, the .exe should inherit the same permissions as the pipeline itself, but it seems like that isn't happening?

Hi there, By From what I've read, the .exe should inherit the same permissions as the pipeline itself, but it seems like that isn't happening?, what do you mean the permissions of pipeline itself? Do you mean the pipeline service account? It has no permissions (RBAC) in your subscription to access the SQL db. From a simple script task, we didn't know where the service principle info used to authenticate the access to your server was retrieved from.

In addition, a service principal exists in Azure AD for the DevOps project doesn't mean any pipeline or the task(s) in it contains the sp info or runs as this sp. Was this what you had been expecting?

What is the script your run on a local machine to authenticate as the sp and then invoked the console app to connect dbs? Has your pipeline definition covers all the required steps? Or it can be invoked anywhere with only the connection string?

Thanks for the replies - the solution seems obvious now.

Thanks for taking time to share the solution. Using the AzureCLI task makes sense as the SP info is stored in the ARM service connection and the pipeline will first run az login against that SP before running any other command, while script task doesn't have the login steps.

Hi @DavidMasters, Good day to you. Would you consider this issue in this post as resolved by your solution below to use AzureCLI task instead? It may help others with similar concerns. Thx.

I just needed to run the script using the AzureCLI@2 task, specifying the service connection:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
      scriptType: 'batch'
      useGlobalConfig: true
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/ef-migrator-exe
        EfMigrator.exe -c "${{ parameters.masterConnectionString }}"   

This I assume creates a token for the service connection, which is then picked up when connecting to the DB.
